# Library module vs library project

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to create the common authenticator and share it between several apps.
It should not contain layouts and other visible elements.

Now I cannot understand what is better for such a purpose: a new library module or a whole library project?

Can I use both these construcs separately in different projects?

Thanx.

Comment: You can create a new library module in current project, and using the module's aar file in other projects.

Comment: Create library project and then include library module in several app. You can import library module without making copy.